# SWF not loading in browser on SX Yosemite

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, flash

just a question, I have been using flash for years and now since i have updated to Yosemite, I cannot load swf files in my browser on my site, I also have been hahving issues with html5 video, this does not play either.

Any thoughts?

here is the page i cannot see. Locally or remotely. I have contacted tech support for my hosting, and on a PC on all browsers the technician said he can see it...They are encoded as usual with H:264 and AAC audio. http://www.julianhunt.ca/ae.html#home

and yes i have been teaching and using flash for 15 years and all the usual settings are okay.

Comment: Questions that post some code or describe what has been done to solve the problem are much more likely to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be path issues between your preloader, player, and content.

It cannot load: http://www.julianhunt.ca/content.swf (404 not found)

[image: io error]

It's not Yosemite, it happens on Mavericks and likely all browsers.

Handling [`IOErrorEvent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IOErrorEvent.html) in your loaders would provide visibility to issues.

Perhaps you recently refactored your site, made updates, or changes to your web host placed different file permissions on assets you host.